# Fiscal year week number with week starting on monday in DAX

Tags: date, ssas, powerbi, dax, tabular

Im new to power Bi. I want to derive a calculated column in date dimension with the week starting with monday. Weeknum function is there but it will give normal week number, not fiscal week number.

screen shot of the date dim:

[image: **screen shot of the date dim**]

Comment: Fiscal Week number? What are you expecting as an output vs what you are getting?

Comment: Now i'm getting week number in normal format. But i wanted the the week number to be in fiscal.